# QString to char* conversion

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qtcore

I was trying to convert a QString to char* type by the following methods, but they don't seem to work.

```
//QLineEdit *line=new QLineEdit();{just to describe what is line here}

QString temp=line->text();
char *str=(char *)malloc(10);
QByteArray ba=temp.toLatin1();
strcpy(str,ba.data());
```

Can you elaborate the possible flaw with this method, or give an alternative method?

Comment: Your example works fine for me, where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for my English but why it isn't right to use such approach?

`QString s("some");
printf(reinterpret_cast<char *>(s.data()));`

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Well, the [Qt FAQ](https://wiki.qt.io/Technical_FAQ#How_can_I_convert_a_QString_to_char.2A_and_vice_versa.3F) says:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
 QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QString str1 = "Test";
  QByteArray ba = str1.toLocal8Bit();
  const char *c_str2 = ba.data();
  printf("str2: %s", c_str2);
  return app.exec();
}
```

So perhaps you're having other problems. How exactly doesn't this work?

Comment: `const char*` and `char*` are not the same type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: writing to QString's contents without it knowing is a horrible idea, hence of course `const char*` is what can really be obtained. The user is free to copy the data to a writable buffer.

Comment: I completely agree. However, the question asked about `char*`, not `char const*`, and your answer simply ignores that fact without mention.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: sometimes the best answer is to unask the question. In other words, to point out that it's not asking the right thing. This answer was accepted by the question poster, so I suppose it hit its target

Comment: There is No difference between   printf("str2: %s",(const char *) ba.data()); and    printf("str2: %s", ba.data());   Wrong Solution

Comment: seems like the FAQ has been updated to use `toLocal8Bit()`?

Comment: This can be shortened to `QString str = "Test"; const char *c_str = str.toLocal8Bit().data();`.

Comment: why this is accepted answer ??? there is difference between const char * and char *

Comment: @user889030 note that this answer is from 9 years ago, and much has changed in Qt. SO answers don't always stand the test of time well for old versions of libraries

Comment: May not be cross-platform solution since the local8Bit encoding can be different depending on the platform. Writing to a file a ba.toLocal8Bit() and then doing fromLocal8Bit from another platform can give unexpected result if the local is different.

Comment: @bur - Can it?  The `QByteArray` returned by `toLocal8Bit()` will go out of scope at the end of the statement, leaving `c_str` pointing to undefined data. (But shortening it further to `printf("str2: %s", str.toLocal8Bit().data());` will work, because the temporary `QByteArray` remains in scope until `printf()` returns.)

Answer (score 75):

Maybe

`my_qstring.toStdString().c_str();`

or safer, as Federico points out:

```
std::string str = my_qstring.toStdString();
const char* p = str.c_str();
```

It's far from optimal, but will do the work.

Comment: This will mess up Unicode characters. A Unicode-friendly solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4644922/238387

Comment: This method is very dangerous and should not be used: `toStdString()` return a new `std::string` object and then the pointer to internal data `const char *` is obtained. However, the string object is immediately destroyed after this statement, so the result pointer probably does not have a valid address if you use it in a subsequent statement.

Comment: @RicoRico It's not the method `toStdString()` that's dangerous; it's the use of raw pointers. Or, more specifically, the use of raw pointers from objects whose scopes aren't well-understood.

Comment: Specifically C++ temporaries normally live until the end of the statement that creates them. So the first form in the answer is ok if it's used in-line in a function call (assuming the function doesn't store the pointer for future use) but it's not ok if it's assigned to a variable.

Comment: As @plugwash says, `f(qstr.toStdString().c_str())` is ok from the point of view of temporary lifetime (extended until the end of `f`). However, the evaluation order of `a.b` is only guaranteed to be `a` before `b` from C++17 onwards. I guess most implementations would already work that way in practice, but strictly speaking I believe it would be UB before C++17

Comment: Other proposed solutions use qstr.toUtf8().data() instead of this proposal, which seems to be a bit better because the function toStdString() ends up using toUtf8() anyway. So, to go more directly to the point, and probably faster, doing qstr.toUtf8().data() is better.

Answer (score 69):

The easiest way to convert a [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details) to **char*** is [qPrintable(const QString& str)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable),
which is a macro expanding to `str.toLocal8Bit().constData()`.

Comment: Why isn't this a more popular answer? I just learned about this by accident while poking around the Qt source, and that's exactly what they do.

Comment: @Phlucious, because: 1) `qPrintable` returns `const char*` not `char*`, `str.toLocal8Bit().data()` returns `char*`. 2) The pointer to `const char*` becomes invalid as soon as you hit a semicolon in the statement where `qPrintable` was used. So `const char* c_ptr = s.toLocal8Bit().constData();` does not make any sense.

Comment: @Phlucious thanks you are life saver :) these all top voted answers are wrong , Question is about char and they are returning const char*

Comment: Is `qPrintable` output guaranteed to be zero terminated?

Comment: @WindyFields - As warned in the `qPrintable()` description: "The char pointer will be invalid after the statement in which qPrintable() is used."

Answer (score 9):

**EDITED**

this way also works

```
QString str ("Something");

char* ch = str.toStdString().c_str();
```

Comment: That looks like a different conversion (`std::string` → `QString`), not what's asked for.

Comment: The pointer returned by c_str() is only valid for the statement that it is on. So using ch for anything is very unsafe...

Answer (score 8):

David's answer works fine if you're only using it for outputting to a file or displaying on the screen, but if a function or library requires a char* for parsing, then this method works best:

```
// copy QString to char*
QString filename = "C:\dev\file.xml";
char* cstr;
string fname = filename.toStdString();
cstr = new char [fname.size()+1];
strcpy( cstr, fname.c_str() );

// function that requires a char* parameter
parseXML(cstr);
```

Answer (score 6):

Qt provides the simplest API

```
const char *qPrintable(const QString &str)
const char *qUtf8Printable(const QString &str)
```

If you want non-const data pointer use

```
str.toLocal8Bit().data()
str.toUtf8().data()
```

Answer (score 4):

Your string may contain non Latin1 characters, which leads to undefined data. It depends of what you mean by "it deosn't seem to work".

Answer (score 4):

If your string contains non-ASCII characters - it's better to do it this way:
`s.toUtf8().data()` (or `s->toUtf8().data()`)

Answer (score 2):

the Correct Solution Would be like this

```
   QString k;
   k = "CRAZYYYQT";
   char ab[16];
   sprintf(ab,"%s",(const char *)((QByteArray)(k.toLatin1()).data()) );
   sprintf(ab,"%s",(const char *)((QByteArray)(k.toStdString()).data()));  
   sprintf(ab,"%s",(const char *)k.toStdString().c_str()  );
   qDebug()<<"--->"<<ab<<"<---";
```

Comment: Forget to use C-style casting.

Answer (score 1):

It is a viable way to use std::vector as an intermediate container:

```
QString dataSrc("FooBar");
QString databa = dataSrc.toUtf8();
std::vector<char> data(databa.begin(), databa.end());
char* pDataChar = data.data();
```