# How to convert QString to std::string?

Tags: c++, qt, type-conversion, qstring

I am trying to do something like this:

```
QString string;
// do things...
std::cout << string << std::endl;
```

but the code doesn't compile.
How to output the content of qstring into the console (e.g. for debugging purposes or other reasons)? How to convert `QString` to `std::string`?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

One of the things you should remember when converting `QString` to `std::string` is the fact that `QString` is UTF-16 encoded while `std::string`... May have any encodings.

So the best would be either:

```
QString qs;

// Either this if you use UTF-8 anywhere
std::string utf8_text = qs.toUtf8().constData();

// or this if you're on Windows :-)
std::string current_locale_text = qs.toLocal8Bit().constData();
```

The suggested (accepted) method may work if you specify codec.

See: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1

Comment: This isn't safe & is slightly slower than the proper way.  You're accessing the data of a QByteArray created on the stack.  The destructor for the QByteArray may be called before the constructor of the STL string.  The safest way to create a helper function. 

`static inline std::string toUtf8(const QString& s)
{
 QByteArray sUtf8 = s.toUtf8();
 return std::string(sUtf8.constData(), sUtf8.size());
}`

Comment: @Vitali not correct. "The destructor for the QByteArray may be called before the constructor of the STL string" is not correct statement: Quoting the standard: 12.2.3 Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created. And the full expression there is `std::string utf8_text = qs.toUtf8().constData();` So your statement is not correct

Comment: That's true - I was thinking about const char *x = qs.ToUtf8().constData().  Still, isn't it easier to just call qs.toStdString()?

Comment: @Vitali No. That loses non-latin1 characters. Try this: `QString s = QString::fromUtf8("árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép ÁRVÍZTŰRŐ TÜKÖRFÚRÓGÉP"); std::cout << s.toStdString() << std::endl; std::cout << s.toUtf8().constData() << std::endl;`. The first is incorrect, the second is perfect. You need an utf8 terminal to test this.

Comment: For what it's worth, `.toStdString()` for me always results in an access violation in the pipe operator, irrespective of the `QString`'s contents (non-latin1 or not). This is on Qt 4.8.3/MSVC++ 10/Win 7.

Comment: @Artyom The answer should be edited because `QByteArray QString::toAscii() const` is [obsolete](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring-obsolete.html#toAscii)

Comment: @notinlist Well, both methods result in the same giberish: "∩┐╜rv∩┐╜zt?r? t∩┐╜k∩┐╜rf∩┐╜r∩┐╜g∩┐╜p ∩┐╜RV∩┐╜ZT?R? T∩┐╜K∩┐╜RF∩┐╜R∩┐╜G∩┐╜P". They are the same at least.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4214397/8533873 should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Artyom I have an issue, while use `toLocal8Bit().constData()`. One file come from U disk, and it's filename with code page `GB2312`, then open it in english area windows, it's code page is `ISO 8859-1`. So, at this moment, if you pass QString to std::string, you will get an error encode. How to fix it?

Answer (score 349):

You can use:

```
QString qs;
// do things
std::cout << qs.toStdString() << std::endl;
```

It internally uses QString::toUtf8() function to create std::string, so it's Unicode safe as well. [Here's](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString) reference documentation for `QString`.

Comment: As of Qt 5.0, `QString::toStdString()` now uses `QString::toUtf8()` to perform the conversion, so the Unicode properties of the string will not be lost (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qstring.html#toStdString).

Comment: And if you want to check the source code for `QString::toStdString`, [here it is](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/source/9754e5a03e4444a18ec7ca1525d196326ff4e038:src/corelib/tools/qstring.h#L1164).

Comment: How can i test to see if it indeed loses the Unicode property? Will using Unicode characters(e.g. say from a language other than English) will do?

Answer (score 37):

If your ultimate aim is to get debugging messages to the console, you can use [qDebug()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html).

You can use like,

`qDebug()<<string;` which will print the contents to the *console*.

This way is better than converting it into `std::string` just for the sake of debugging messages.

Comment: qDebug() would be much better, because it supports more Qt types.

Answer (score 26):

```
QString qstr;
std::string str = qstr.toStdString();
```

However, if you're using Qt:

```
QTextStream out(stdout);
out << qstr;
```

Comment: I had tried out << qstr first, before asking, but it didn't compile. It works with qstr.toStdString(), though.

Comment: I don't think so. You tried std::cout << qstr, not QTextString(stdout) << qstr;

Answer (score 19):

Best thing to do would be to overload operator<< yourself, so that QString can be passed as a type to any library expecting an output-able type.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, const QString& string) {
    return str << string.toStdString();
}
```

Comment: Why the down votes, folks? It's an overkill in my case, but who knows, it might be useful (to me or someone else).

Comment: I like this because Qt have a habit of changing the way their strings work - and this puts the conversion in one place.

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to the proposed:

```
QString qs;
std::string current_locale_text = qs.toLocal8Bit().constData();
```

could be:

```
QString qs;
std::string current_locale_text = qPrintable(qs);
```

See [qPrintable documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qPrintable), a macro delivering a const char * from QtGlobal.

Comment: this works even with a Qt-Build with `-no-stl`-Option set. [some more info](http://asmaloney.com/2011/11/code/qstringtostdstring-qstringfromstdstring-and-no-stl/)

Answer (score 8):

The simplest way would be `QString::toStdString()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this;

```
QString data;
data.toStdString().c_str();
```

Comment: please add some details as to what the mistake was and why your answer works

Answer (score 1):

There is also the option to use [qPrintable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qPrintable) or [qUtf8Printable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qUtf8Printable)

E.g.:

```
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    QString myString = "Hello World";

    // Using qPrintable
    std::cout << "qPrintable: " << qPrintable(myString) << std::endl;

    // Using qUtf8Printable
    std::cout << "qUtf8Printable: " << qUtf8Printable(myString) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 QString data;
   data.toStdString().c_str();
```

### could even throw exception on VS2017 compiler in xstring

```
 ~basic_string() _NOEXCEPT
        {   // destroy the string
        _Tidy_deallocate();
        }
```

the right way ( secure - no exception) is how is explained above from Artyom

```
 QString qs;

    // Either this if you use UTF-8 anywhere
    std::string utf8_text = qs.toUtf8().constData();

    // or this if you're on Windows :-)
    std::string current_locale_text = qs.toLocal8Bit().constData();
```

Answer (score 0):

HA~I finally find the answer which I can run! Share to you now~

```
QString qStr = "Hello world";
QByteArray qByteArray = qStr.toUtf8();
char* cStr = qByteArray.data();
const char* test = cStr;
qDebug()<<test<<endl;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
#include <QDebug>
QString string;
// do things...
qDebug() << "right" << string << std::endl;
```

Comment: The question is very clear: convert QString to std::string, not to print it.

Comment: @eyllanesc the question text says "How to output the content of qstring into the console?"  , it seems OP assumes converting to std::string is the only way.  It's really two questions being asked at once .

Comment: @M.M The question seems unclear since the question in the title says *How to convert QString to std::string?*, Maybe it's an XY problem.