# Call to a function is ambiguious

Tags: c++, function-calls

I am trying to build a program but got an error:

```
application_ob.cpp: In member function 'void ApplicationWindow::OBNewLoad(QString, QString)':
application_ob.cpp:103:41: error: call of overloaded 'FormatFromExt(QString&)' is ambiguous
application_ob.cpp:103:41: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/obconversion.h:81:24: note: static OpenBabel::OBFormat* OpenBabel::OBConversion::FormatFromExt(const char*)
/usr/include/openbabel-2.0/openbabel/obconversion.h:84:24: note: static OpenBabel::OBFormat* OpenBabel::OBConversion::FormatFromExt(std::string)
```

How can I patch it so to get normal build? Please explain in simple way because I do not know C++.

Comment: If you do not know C++, you should contact the developers who [arguably] do, and get them to fix their product.

Answer (score 2):

Line 103 of `application_ob.cpp` probably reads something like:

```
FormatFromExt(qs);
```

The immediate solution would be to change this (or its equivalent) to

```
FormatFromExt(qs.toStdString());
```

However, we do not have enough information regarding the possible contents of `qs` to tell if the above method will work when dealing with non-latin characters. Better alternatives are 
presented in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring/4644922#4644922), but to choose between them we have to know what kind of data we are dealing with.

Comment: Oddly, I can't see any implicit conversion to `std::string` _or_ `char const*` from [`QString`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html), so why would _either_ overload be a candidate?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Absolutely no idea about that... maybe the compiler is just saying "look, there's two methods with that name I could call here, but none with the argument you 're giving me".

Comment: Nah, it explicitly says there are two candidates. Not being able to find a matching function is a different beast.

Comment: @tomalak see the documentation for macro "QT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII" on that page.

Comment: @Johannes: Ah, thanks. Odd that the implicit conversions themselves aren't documented; only how to disable them.

Comment: @Tomalak weird that it shows the `std::string` overload though. `operator char const*` won't be able to match up with a `std::string` function parameter.

Comment: Is it possible to just specify which one of the two we want without making implicit type conversion?

Comment: Your suggestion failed: 
application_ob.cpp: In member function 'void ApplicationWindow::OBNewLoad(QString, QString)':
application_ob.cpp:103:42: error: 'class QString' has no member named 'toStdString'

Comment: @Anixx: Well, [it does, unless you have stdlib compatibility disabled](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html#toStdString). But then if you did this problem wouldn't have come up in the first place. Must be a really old version of Qt?