# Qt error: 'const class QString' has no member named 'toStdString'

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I am getting this error `error: 'const class QString' has no member named 'toStdString'` though `QString` has it. [(link)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#toStdString).

The code

```
    std::string Message::toStdString() const 
    {
        return m_string.toStdString();
    }
```

Comment: "This operator is only available if Qt is configured with STL compatibility enabled."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer directly copied from here:

[How to convert QString to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring)

```
QString qs;

// Either this if you use UTF-8 anywhere
std::string utf8_text = qs.toUtf8().constData();

// or this if you on Windows :-)
std::string current_locale_text = qs.toLocal8Bit().constData();
```

Comment: This happens when Qt was not compiled with STL support.

Comment: what an elegant, intuitive design!