# QHash iterator example - no match for operator <<?

Tags: c++, qt, qhash

Learning QT, i`m trying to compile first example from http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qhash-iterator.html

My code

```
#include <QHash>
#include <iostream>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QHash<QString, int> hash;
    hash.insert("January", 1);
    hash.insert("February", 2);
    hash.insert("December", 12);

    QHash<QString, int>::iterator i;
    for (i = hash.begin(); i != hash.end(); ++i)
        std::cout << i.key() << ": " << i.value() << std::endl;

}
```

is not compiling. I get this error:

> main.cpp:14: error: no match for 'operator<<'
>   in 'std::cout << i.QHash::iterator::key with Key = QString, T
>   = int'

and i have no idea what is wrong. Code is pretty much copy-pasted from docs. 
Am i missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `std::cout` doesn't work with `QString`. Try using `QString::toStdString()`, or you can also use `qDebug()` instead of `cout`

See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring) for details.