# PushBack (push_back()) elements of QStringList to vector<string>

Tags: c++, qt, vector

How can I access elements of `QStringList` in a `vector<string>` type. `push_back` doesn't work. `insert`ing too needs another `vector` type only.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QStringList>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
        std::vector<string> vec;
        QString winter = "December, January, February";
        QString spring = "March, April, May";
        QString summer = "June, July, August";
        QString fall = "September, October, November";
        QStringList list;
        list << winter;
        list += spring;
        list.append(summer);
        list << fall;
        qDebug() << "The Spring months are: " << list[1] ;
        qDebug() << list.size();

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
        //vec.push_back(list[i]);
        }
        exit(0);
        return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `list[i]` are `QString`s, not `std::string`s. Try `list[i].toStdString()` instead.

Comment: Why not? `vec.push_back(list[i].toStdString());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
foreach( QString str, list) {
  vec.push_back(str.toStdString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

QString isn't std::string.  You can't add it directly to a vector of std::string.  You have to convert it to a std::string first.

Also, a QString is a UTF-16 string, and is incompatable with a UTF-8 std::string, so can use std::wstring like this

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
   vec.push_back(list[i].constData());
}
```

Or a std::string like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
{
   vec.push_back(list[i].toUtf8().constData());
}
```

Hope this works/helps

Source:

[How to convert QString to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring)

Comment: `list[i].toSdtString()` will work better (or even `list[i].toStdWString()` for the UTF16 variant)