# What would be most efficient way to compare QString and char*

Tags: performance, qt, malloc, qstring

What would be most efficient way to compare QString and char*

`if( mystring == mycharstar ) {}`  will perform malloc,

and

`if(strcmp(mystring.toLocal8Bit().constData(),mycharstar ) == 0) {}`

Will allocate a `QByteArray`

I would like to not have any allocation happening,
would would you guys recommend?

What about

`if(mystring == QLatin1String(mycharstar))`

Would it be any better?

Comment: Instinctively I would do `mystring.toAscii() == mycharstar`, but I haven't profiled, so don't listen to me.

Comment: why use a char* and not a std::string ?

Comment: tux3 - to Ascii will allocate also and will do a conversion.

Comment: All depends what encoding you want to use. You will have to make your own compare function probably

Answer (score 5):

There is no "efficient" way that only uses casts. This is because `QtString` internally uses 16 bits to encode a single character while C strings use only 8 bits. That means any comparison based on memory pointers will simply almost always return `false`.

That's why you have to encode the 16 bit wide characters of `QtString` to the same encoding as your C string and that always needs at least one call to `malloc()`.

See also: [How to convert QString to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring/4644922#4644922)

Answer (score 2):

It could be `if( mystring == QLatin1String(mycharstar) )`, as suggested [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Using_QString_Effectively).