# No output display in console when running a function

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem where I can't seem to get a output to display in a console when doing it through a function.

It works when doing it through `Main()`, but just blank when doing it through the function.

Below is some of my code:

```
#include "ConferencePaper.h"
#include "JournalArticle.h"
#include "Reference.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTextStream>

QTextStream cout(stdout);

int main()
{
//QApplication app(argc, argv);
QStringList list1;
list1 << "This is a test";

Reference a("Marius",list1,1,"c"); //Instance of the Reference class created      with parameter values
cout << "Title: " << a.getTitle(); //This works fine
a.toString();

return 0;

}
```

```
//Reference Function

#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTextStream>
#include "Reference.h"

Reference::Reference(QString ti, QStringList as, int ye, QString id): title(ti), authors(as), year(ye), refID(id){}

QString Reference::toString()
{
return QString("Title: %1\n") .arg(getTitle()); //Does not display anything

}
```

Comment: How do you expect `toString` to display anything? It just returns a `QString` to the caller, nowhere in it you seem to mention any IO function.

Comment: Thank you Andreas.  Bit of a blond moment :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your `toString()` method:

```
QString Reference::toString() {
  return QString("Title: %1\n") .arg(getTitle()); //Does not display anything
}
```

there is nothing which could cause to print anything on the console. You are simply **returning** the string as a result of that method.

To display something, you need to output the string which is returned from the method, e.g. in your `main()` function like

```
cout << a.toString().toUtf8().constData();
```

or

```
cout << a.toString().toLocal8Bit().constData();
```

Note that you need to convert your `QString` to a data type for which a `<<` operator is available for `ostream`. See also [How to convert QString to std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring)

Comment: It should probably be `toLocal8Bit()` instead of `toUtf8()` for this to work fine on Windows and older Linux.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above several times, X.toString(); would just return QString to a caller, then depending on what you're trying to achieve you may:

- print it to console using cout << ...
- print it to Application Output pane in your Qt Creator using qDebug() << ...

  (see [QDebug Class reference](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html) for details, it's pretty common debugging technique)