# Converting QString to char*

Tags: c++, string, qt, qt4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [QString to char conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523765/qstring-to-char-conversion)

I have a function (fopen in STL) that gives a char* argument as a path in my computer, but I must use QString in that place so it doesn't work.

How can I convert QString to char* to solve this problem?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

See [here at How can I convert a QString to char* and vice versa?](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/how_can_i_convert_a_qstring_to_char_and_vice_versa)

> In order to convert a QString to a
>   char*, then you first need to get a
>   latin1 representation of the string by
>   calling toLatin1() on it which will
>   return a QByteArray. Then call data()
>   on the QByteArray to get a pointer to
>   the data stored in the byte array. See
>   the documentation:
>
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLatin1
>   https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#data
>
> See the following example for a
>   demonstration:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char **argv)
> {
>  QApplication app(argc, argv);
>   QString str1 = "Test";
>   QByteArray ba = str1.toLatin1();
>   const char *c_str2 = ba.data();
>   printf("str2: %s", c_str2);
>   return app.exec();
> }
> ```
>
> Note that it is necessary to store the
>   bytearray before you call data() on
>   it, a call like the following
>
> ```
> const char *c_str2 = str2.toLatin1().data();
> ```
>
> will make the application crash as the
>   QByteArray has not been stored and
>   hence no longer exists
>
> To convert a char* to a QString you
>   can use the QString constructor that
>   takes a QLatin1String, e.g:
>
> ```
> QString string = QString(QLatin1String(c_str2)) ;
> ```
>
> See the documentation:
>
> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlatin1string.html

Of course, I discovered there is another way from this [previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring/4644922#4644922):

```
QString qs;

// Either this if you use UTF-8 anywhere
std::string utf8_text = qs.toUtf8().constData();

// or this if you on Windows :-)
std::string current_locale_text = qs.toLocal8Bit().constData();
```

Comment: I think the wording needs to change. The statement `const char *c_str2 = str2.toLatin1().data();` should work fine. Unfortunately after the ';' the temporary QByteArray created by toLatin1() has been destroyed so `c_str2` now has an invalid pointer. Conversely you could use it in a call `doStuff(str2.toLatin1().data());` as the QByteArray is not destroyed until the ';' Thus: `printf("str2: %s", str2.toLatin1().data());` Should be OK.

Comment: @Martin: I am just quoting Qt.

Comment: This.  I have spent half of today debugging a problem caused by the underlying QByteArray being destroyed.  It's a real pain to have to store the byte array, but it seems to be necessary.

Comment: Loki's comment seems spot-on. I use someFunction(myQString.toUtf8().constData()); all the time and it works fine, but if you try to use char *myCString = myQString.toUtf8().constData(); and then use myCString, you'll end up with a C string that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, depending on whether the QByteArray happens to still be valid or not when you access its contents via a C pointer. Definitely need to be careful here!

Comment: i was hopping for char* not const char *

Comment: Note: [toLocal8Bit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit) *If this string contains any characters that cannot be encoded in the locale, the returned byte array is undefined. Those characters may be suppressed or replaced by another.* -- it sounds like this is only valid if you know ahead of time that the `QString` contains only valid Latin1 characters.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [QFile](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qfile.html) rather than std::fstream.

```
QFile           file(qString);
```

Alternatively convert the QString into a char* as follows:

```
std::ifstream   file(qString.toLatin1().data());
```

The [QString](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstring.html) is in UTF-16 so it is converted toLatin1() here but QString has a couple of different conversions including toUtf8() (check your file-system it may use UTF-8).

As noted by @0A0D above: **don't** store the char* in a variable without also getting a local copy of the QByteArray.

```
char const*      fileName = qString.toLatin1().data();
std::ifstream    file(fileName);  // fileName not valid here.
```

This is because toLatin1() returns an object of QByteArray. As it is not actually bound to a variable it is a temporary that is destroyed at the end of the expression. Thus the call to data() here returns a pointer to an internal structure that no longer exists after the ';'.