# QString to char*

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to convert QString into char*.
The code that i have been using is

```
QString username = useradd->text();
QByteArray un=username.toLatin1();
const char *str = un.data();
```

Where `useradd` is the name given to "lineedit"

On compilation the following error occurs

> class `QString` has no member named `toLatin1`

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another class with the same name defined somewhere? or your headers aren't broken?

Comment: Why are you trying to use Latin1? It's almost 2015 outside for Bob's sake! Use UTF-8.

Comment: Duplicate of duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505221/converting-qstring-to-char

Comment: i think i have given headers properly

Comment: the same error is coming with UTF-8 also

Answer (score 1):

This way: `QString::toStdString()::c_str()`

Comment: Be sure to not take .c_str() on a temporary.

Comment: please can you suggest anything using QByteArray because i am not being able to define it correctly as i am new to QT3.3

Comment: Qt3.3? I hope this is a legacy program, as Qt 4.8 is really as far back in time as you probably want to go otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only once, like in a debug line, use this:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qPrintable

> This is equivalent to str.toLocal8Bit().constData().

```
qDebug() << qPrintable(myString);
```