# Cannot Convert QString to const Char *

Tags: c++, c, qt, qstring

I need to convert QString to const char* then have to pass to another function

My code looks,

```
QString port = "1234";
const char *Port = port.toLatin1().data();
setport(Port); //function call
```

Function

```
void setport(const char *Port){
  int p = atoi(Port); // here I am getting 0 instead 1234
}
```

I am using Qt5.4.1

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks 
Haris

Comment: I found the answer already there and using the code as shown in my Question, Only difference is the atoi() function.

Comment: Try QString port = "1234";
 QByteArray ba = port.toLatin1();
 const char *Port = ba.data();

Comment: Hi thanks it works, but why my method wont work which doing the same in single step.

Comment: I have tried it myself ... but I have no idea, why it is not working ^^ sry

Comment: Anyway the issue solved, thanks once again.

Comment: You don't say what error you see / behaviour you see.

Comment: @Haris There is a good explanation why you need to store QByteArray here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505221/converting-qstring-to-char

Comment: @HamishMoffatt I am getting 0 while using atoi(), I explained that as a comment in above code.