# qFatal argument: conversion of QString to const char* results in warning "format string is not a string literal"

Tags: c++, qt, c-strings, llvm-clang, string-conversion

Under Qt5.9 and clang++-6.0.0,

```
QString ret;
qFatal(ret.toLatin1().constData());
```

yields a warning "format string is not a string literal".

What's wrong, and what is the right way to accomplish the required conversion from QString to a C string?

PS: A closely related question is [Converting QString to char*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505221/converting-qstring-to-char). Here, however, different solutions are possible thanks to the printf-like argument list of qFatal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting QString to char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505221/converting-qstring-to-char)

Comment: Edited question to say how it differs from #5505221 (Converting QString to char*)

Comment: I recommend you modify the title to indicate that heart of the issue is `qFatal` usage, it will be much more useful reference.

Comment: good point, done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qFatal` allows for the variadic `...` argument known from `printf`. Thus

```
qFatal("%s", ret.toLatin1().constData());
```

and the warning is gone.