# Using system command in Qt

Tags: qt

How can I use the `system` command where the command is written in a QString?

Like:

```
QString command="chmod -R 777 /opt/QT/examples/code/TestGUI/Data";    
system(command);
```

While compiling, I get this error:

```
cannot convert ‘QString’ to ‘const char*’
  for argument ‘1’ to ‘int system(const char*)’
```

Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [QString to char conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523765/qstring-to-char-conversion)

Answer (score 12):

Use the [`qPrintable()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtglobal.html#qPrintable) macro

`system(qPrintable(command));`

Comment: Hey, thanks! I didn't know about `qPrintable`. One learns something every day.

Answer (score 8):

You need get the raw character array from the QString.  Here is one way:

```
system(command.toStdString().c_str());
```

Answer (score 7):

Ankur Gupta wrote, use QProcess static function ([link to description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#execute-2)):

```
int QProcess::execute ( const QString & program )
```

In your situation:

```
QProcess::execute ("chmod -R 777 /opt/QT/examples/code/TestGUI/Data");
```

Answer (score 6):

QProcess class http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html. It's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To change permission you could use setPermissions of QFile

Answer (score 0):

you can convert `QString` to `const char*`.

if your string is in UTF8, then you can use:

```
const char* my_command = command.toUtf8().constData() ;
system(my_command);
```

else if your string is not in UTF8, then you can use:

```
command.toLatin1().constData() ;
system(my_command);
```

in this case second one is what you want.

Comment: I kno0w this  post is ancient , but   QProcess::execute ("service bluetooth status"); "forwards results to calling process" -- HOW to write a  C++ code to accomplish  such "forwarding"?