# c++ fstreams open file with utf-16 name

Tags: c++, windows, qt

At first I built my project on Linux and it was built around streams.

When I started moving to Windows I ran into some problems.

I have a name of the file that I want to open in UTF-16 encoding.
[image]

I  try to do it using fstream:

```
QString source;  // content of  source  is shown on image
char *op= (char *) source.data();
fstream stream(op, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

But file cannot be opened. 

When I check it,

```
 if(!stream.is_open())
   {}  // I always get that  it's not opened. But file indeed exists.
```

I tried to do it with wstream. But result is the same, because wstream accepts only char * too.  As  I understand it's so , because  string , that is sent as char * , is truncated after the first zero and only one symbol of the file's name is sent, so  file is never found.   I know wfstream in Vissual studio can accept wchar_t * line as name, but compiler of my choice is MinGW and it doesn't have such signature for wstring constructor.

Is there any way to do it with STL streams?

**ADDITION**
That string can contaion not only Ascii symbols, it can contain Russian, German, Chinese symbols simultaneously. I don't want limit myself only to  ASCII or local encoding.

**NEXT ADDITION**
Also data can be different, not only ASCII, otherwise  I wouldn't bother myself with Unicode at all.
 E.g.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2523786/1458030

Comment: @qPCR4vir: How is it related?

Comment: Why are you using Qt but prefer `std::fstream` over `QFile`?

Comment: I don't want to attach me to it too close. I want to leave some chance to free myself from it

Answer (score 3):

[Boost::Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) especially the [fstream.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#File-streams) header may help.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using MSVC and it's implementation of the c++ standard library, something like this should work:

```
QString source;  // content of  source  is shown on image
wchar_t *op= source.data();
fstream stream(op, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
```

This works because the Microsoft c++ implementation has an extension to allow fstream to be opened with a wide character string.

Comment: eh, unfortunately, I use Mingw(

Comment: Then boost::filesystem's fstream implementation is the best answer.  There may also be a solution using mingw and libstdc++ extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the UTF-16 string using [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with CP_ACP before passing the filename to fstream.

Comment: Not every file is accessible that way.  If a filename has a char that is not present in the current ANSI code page ...

Comment: Yes, but that's a limitation of the fstream implementation.

Comment: Saying that the `fstream`s are limited and then pretending the problem doesn't exist seems like a bad idea to me.  Is there some non-portable C++ class that will ultimately call `CreateFileW` to open the file?  Seems like that would suit the questioner much better.

Comment: For one, `QFile` has been suggested.