# How to obtain const char * from QString

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qstring, qtcore

I have read a string in from an XML file with UTF8 encoding. I store this value in a `QString` object and concatenate it with some other information. I can see in the QtCreator debugger that the `QString` holds the desired value.

I need to pass this string to another library that takes a `const char *` argument. How do I obtain the `const char *` please? I've tried `toLocal8bit()`, `toLatin1()`, `toUtf8()` all with no luck. Seems like I am missing something...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214369/how-to-convert-qstring-to-stdstring

Comment: @MinLin: that thread is about std string, *not* const char*.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Well, in the answer the rvalue is const char*, just implicitly converted to the lvalue which is a std string

Comment: @MinLin: std::string and QString should not be mixed IMO as it is not necessary. Hence, that is a different use case, so a different question. It is better to go through qt types without mixing std in. See my answer below.

Comment: @LaszloPapp Well, your answer is correct. What I mean is that in that post though it wants a std string, the right hand side is a const char*, and I think readers of that post should be able to figure out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QString to char\* conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523765/qstring-to-char-conversion)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I need to pass this string to another library that takes a const char
>   * argument. How do I obtain the const char * please? I've tried toLocal8bit(), toLatin1(), toUtf8() all with no luck. Seems like I am
>   missing something...

Because if you try those, you only get a `QByteArray` back as opposed to a `const char*`. You could use the [constData()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qbytearray.html#constData) method on the `QByteArray` you got that way, and then you will have the desired result.

Mixing `std::string` and `QString` is not necessary, hence it is better to go through the qt types (`QString -> QByteArray -> const char*`) without introducing `std::string` in here.

Where you use `toLocal8bit()`, `toLatin1()` or `toUtf8()` depends on your encoding, so that is a different question to the main one in here. They will all return a `QByteArray` to you.

Note: you should avoid using `toAscii()` though as that is deprecated in Qt 5 for good.