# Access Reading Violation when writing a DICOM with vtkDICOMWriter

Tags: c++, qt, vtk, dicom

I'm trying to write vtkImageData as a DICOM. I keep getting an "Access Reading Violation" when I try to write the image.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFDA30ECA50 : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000001BD38D5C000

Here is my code:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMWriter> dcmWriter = vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMWriter>::New();
dcmWriter->SetInputData(testDat);
dcmWriter->SetFileName(fullPath.toStdString().c_str());
dcmWriter->Update(); // this line breaks
dcmWriter->Write();
```

`testDat` is a `vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageData>` type and has data in it. Any thoughts on whats causing the error? I can't find anything similar online.

I followed this example: https://github.com/dgobbi/vtk-dicom/blob/master/Examples/TestDICOMWriter.cxx

I don't have metadata, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Have you tried a different writer for the same data? That way you can rule out a problem with `testDat`.

Comment: I tried vtk's TIFF reader and hard coding the file path using " ". Everything worked as expected. However hard coding the path using " " with the DICOM writer did not work. Yes it is Qt (QString), I was trying to convert it to const char*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523765/qstring-to-char-conversion

Comment: where does "testDat" come from?

Comment: testDat is vtkImageData

Answer (score 0):

I need to make some guesses here because you didn't post all of your code, but I suspect that the problem happens in the following line:

```
dcmWriter->SetFileName(fullPath.toStdString().c_str());
```

`toStdString()` is most probably returning a temporary `std::string` (`fullPath` looks like a Qt [`QString`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toStdString)), on which you call `c_str()`. After the statement, your temporary is destroyed and whatever you have passed to `SetFileName` is now a dangling pointer. Hence the segfault.

Try the following instead::

```
const auto pathString = fullPath.toStdString();
dcmWriter->SetFileName(pathString.c_str());
```

This should hopefully work fine. Even if not, it definitely is an issue with your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I even tried hard coding the path using " " and I still get the access violation reading location. Its crashing on the `dcmWriter->Update()`, and if I comment out the `Update()` line, it will crash on the `dcmWriter->Write()` line.

Comment: Are you using the correct `vtk-dicom` binaries for your compiler?

Answer (score 0):

These lines are from the example you posted:

```
writer->SetFilePrefix("/tmp");
writer->SetFilePattern("%s/IM-0001-%04.4d.dcm");
```

and you use

```
dcmWriter->SetFileName(fullPath.toStdString().c_str());
```

It seems that vtkDICOMWriter writes several files so you probably need to provide a file pattern. Anyway, it's hard to guess why it gives a reading error and it's hard to help if you don't post a full working example.

Last, vtkDICOMWriter is not a class from vtk, it was released separetely (it seems) in 2017. This means it's not tested against the rest of VTK at every new release.