# String cast to const char*

Tags: c++, qt

I use in my project QString but In some cases I have to transfer this to an external SDK, that expect null terminated const char*. For this I use:

```
QByteArray folderName = ((QDataItem*)(*it))->GetName().toUtf8();
folderName.append('\0');
dir.lpszDir = folderName;
```

Is casting the right way here? I assume I have to cast it with dynamic cast? Or is there a better way to bring the "GetName()" to a const char*?

Comment: I don't see `QDataItem` in the [list of Qt classes](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html#d). What is it / where does it come from?

Comment: `folderName.constData()` may be right option, if the lifetime matches.

Comment: @hyde ... QT tells me that it is not compatible. Assign qchar * to const char*

Comment: @ingo You're omitting something relevant now, because [*QByteArray::constData()*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#constData) definitely returns just that, `const char*`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QString to char\* conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523765/qstring-to-char-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like that in my project.

```
 QString stringMessage = "something";
 char* charMessage = new char[stringMessage.size() + 1];

 std::memcpy(charMessage, stringMessage.toLocal8Bit().data(), static_cast<size_t>(stringMessage.size() + 1));
```

Comment: you didn't allocate memory for `charMessage`

Comment: My bad. I've fixed it.