# QT Model view with translation

Tags: qt, translation

I am using QT and lately got into translations using tr() function.

Is it possible to work with model/view architecture and translations with QT?
By that I mean real-time translation of model data - let's say I have a data like that:

```
n age    ready
1 old    yes
2 young  no
3 old    yes
4 young  yes
5 old    yes
6 old    yes
7 medium no
8 medium no
9 medium no
```

And I would like to define a translation for these fixed values in real-time when it gets out of database.
(e.g.

```
yes - tak
no - nie
...
```

I have tried to tr() values after getting them from database, but I cannot use QString at tr()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tr()` requires `const char *` so all you need to do is to convert your `QString` to `const char *`. Read this [QString to char* conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523765/qstring-to-char-conversion)

You can use for example `tr(yourstring.toUtf8().constData())`.